# How to unit test Template 10's RaisePropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, uwp, template10

I'm working on a UWP application using Template10. I want to unit test my view models however I'm struggling to find a way to verify that a view model raised its `PropertyChanged` event for a particular property. I can test a standard `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemetation, but not Template10's one (with FluentAssertions for example.)

Any hints to put me in a right direction?

The relevant implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs).

Comment: Does not the Template 10 view model implement INotifyPropertyChaged?

Answer (score 0):

[`ViewModelBase`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Mvvm/ViewModelBase.cs) is inherited from derived classes that implement `INofitypropertChanged`

so you can add an event handler to the PropertyChanged event.

```cs
//Arrange
var expected = "MyProperty";
var actual = string.Empty;

var viewModel = {...some calss that inherits from ViewModelBase};

viewModel.PropertChanged += (s,e) => {
    actual = e.PropertyName;
}

//Act
viewModel.MyProperty = "Test";

//Assert
actual.Should().Be(expected);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried something similar already however it is not working - the test exits with System.InvalidOperationException with message of "A method was called at an unexpected time. Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created". I've updated the question with a link to the implementation.

Comment: Also include the test that is failing as a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: Once you have a solution, please post it https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT I searched there first and saw that someone had proposed a PR but can no longer find it implemented in the code base https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/pull/236

Comment: I believe this line is the culprit https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs#L35

Comment: `BindableBase` is tightly coupled to some static calls that could prove to be troublesome when the class is being tested in isolation.